# Remove file name when recursively counting number of occurrences of a pattern

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, grep

When I run my grep command:

`grep -rc 'PATTERN' .`

it prints out the number of lines that the pattern occurs, but it looks like this:

`./hotel_232424.dat:234`

and so on...

How would I remove the `./hotel_232424.dat:` part and just print out the number?

Comment: Do you want one number per line for each file without knowing which file that number correspond to? Or just one number for the number of occurrences in all the files?

Comment: One number per line for each file

Answer (score 2):

With the GNU implementation of `grep`, you have the `-h`/`--no-filename` option for that.

```
$ grep -rc PATTERN .
./b:1
./a:0
./1/2/c:2
$ grep -rhc PATTERN .
1
0
2
```

The portable/standard equivalent would be:

```
$ find . -type f -exec grep -c PATTERN {} \;
0
2
1
```

but would mean running one `grep` invocation per file.

If instead, you want the total number of occurrences (1+2 = 3 here), you could do (portably):

```
$ find . -type f -exec cat {} + | grep -c PATTERN
3
```

(note that if some of the files have data after their last line (so, non-text files), that could mess-up the result)

Or, with a `grep` supporting `-r` like yours:

```
$ grep -r PATTERN . | wc -l
3
```